# JComponent size independent from screen size

Tags: java, swing, dimension, preferredsize

My application is rich of JPanels and other Swing components that display something. I would like that these JComponents' dimension to be independent from screen size, such as my GUI will be ok at different resolution. I thought to do something like this in my code

```
public class myPanel extends JPanel {
 //constructors and other useful methods

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  Dimension screen_size=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  return new Dimension (0.50*screen_size.width, 0.30*screen_size.height); }
```

In a nutshell, give the dimension to the JPanel in percent of the screen size. Is that good? There isn't a fast way? Because I should do that for every JComponent I use. What should I do?
PS: Let's assume that I use Manager Layouts that honor the preferred size.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? And what do you mean with "fast" - short execution time or short coding time?

Comment: AFAIK the preferred way would be to use layout managers and let them decide the size of your components. Screen size would just influence window size and the layout managers would propagate that to all components. If you can't do what you want with the built-in layout managers have a look at third party libraries like [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) where you could define your panel to occupy 50% of the window width and 30% of its height.

Answer (score 0):

The layout `GridBagLayout` allows you to specify sizes as weights of the columns. If you do that and specify all components to fill their grid cell then you will get your desired behavior.

For example 3 components with:

```
weightx 2, weightx 1, weightx 1
```

Then the first component will always use 50% of the window, the next two 25% of the window each. This will also automatically re-size as you resize the window, not just the monitor.

You should be aware that things like text inside controls will not automatically resize with the controls though.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html